# Virtual layer in QGIS from generated geometry by a multi table join

Tags: qgis, spatial-join, virtual-layer

I have a Spatialite database with three tables. I'd like to draw a center point of a line (by using `ST_Line_Interpolate_Point`) that is generated by a multi table join.

The first table has the organizational elements that each should cause a point beeing drawn. The second table has a linked dataset with additional information stored that can be linked to multiple organizational elements (1:n). The third table has spatial information in terms of a linestring for the second table which has two foreign keys of the third table  to define left and right boundaries. I want to take the forst points of the right and left lines and draw a virtual line whereon I can apply the `ST_Line_Interpolate_Point` function on. **This is generally no problem and not the question on how to do so!**.

The problem starts here: I get a geometry as a result that gives me a point which is good. (Tested in the QGIS DB manager) But if I try to let this be drawn in a virtual layer it doesn't find my spatial column. If I remove it from the bracket in the selected input layers in the virtual layer dialog it will be recognized in the query but the column value seems to stay empty.

I also tried to put the query into a view and store it in the Spatialite table which causes valid results, but as soon as I try to query the results into a layer or a virtual layer QGIS fails to add it as it seems to not recognize the SRID of the aggregated column.

Any tips on how I could achieve this multi table join into a view and then generate the center line points?

*Sorry that I can't be more specific in the table structure as it is under an NDA* :(

Comment: Virtual layers can also be defined from the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` There you can declare which geometry column should be used, CRS etc

Comment: Thank you @JGH, I already tried that, but the problem occurs as soon as I define the geometry column. I try to provide a screenshot today.